# ie 11 некорректно работает с flex?

Tags: html, css, css3, internet-explorer

Разбирался с flex, переделал тестовый макет на flex

и столкнулся с проблемой что ie 11 не отрабатывает flex-wrap: wrap если в родителях элемента есть flex элементы ...

в остальных браузерах всё ок.

http://codepen.io/sharov/pen/doeLZy/

не отрабатывает

```
.phones { flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Работает... Но он себя как-то по-табличному повёл и хочет увидеть фиксированную ширину. Как вариант, подходит такой костыль:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrYzm

```
.phones {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(100vw - 230px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Модуль **Flexible Box Layout** в старых браузерах реализован со множеством багов.

Существует страница, курируемая сообществом flexbox, в котором описаны все известные баги **Flexible Box Layout** и кросс-браузерные способы их решения:

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs